# Prove $T_2\circ T_1$ isn't injective according to their rank

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T_1 : U \rightarrow V$ and $T_2 : V\rightarrow W$ be linear maps such that $rkT_1 > rkT_2$. Prove that $T_2\circ T_1$ isn't injective.

I proved that $nullT_2>0$ and from that I can understand $T_2$ isn't injective (I thought it was enough but I was wrong), so how can I explain this is impact the Nullity of $T_2\circ T_1$?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Can you write an equivalent form of being injective with an expression involving $rk$ ?

Comment: did you mean $dim(v)>rkT_1$?

Comment: No, it's exactly the opposite ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S$ be the restriction of $T_2$ to the range of $T_1$. If $T_2 \circ T_1$ is injective then $S$ is injective so the dimension of the range of $T_1$ is less than or equal to the dimension of the range  $S$ which is contained in the range of $T_2$.  Can you finish?

To answer the question you have asked in a comment below take $U=\mathbb R, V=\mathbb R^{2}, W=\mathbb R$. Let $T_1(x)=(x,0)$ and $T_2(x,y)=x+y$. Then $(T_2 \circ T_1) (x)=T_2(x,0)=x$ so $T_2\circ T_1$ is injective. But $T_2$ is not injective bacause $T_2(1,-1)=0=T_2 (0,0)$ and $(1,-1) \neq (0,0)$.

Comment: I can see that. Is it correct to say that the composition is injective only if both $T_1$ and $T_2$ are injective?

Comment: I thought it is correct, but I've been told I was wrong and didn't understand why. That is basically my question.

Comment: @GiladTicher I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

By the Rank-nullity Theorem, an abbreviation reads:

$T_2V = T_2V+\text{ker}T_2T_1\geq T_2T_1U+\text{ker}T_2T_1=U=T_1U+\ker{T_1} > T_2V + \text{ker}T_1$.

It follows that $\text{dim}(T_2V) > \text{dim}(T_2V)$. This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

We have $rk(T_2 T_1) \leq rk(T_2)$ because $Im(T_2T_1) \subset Im(T_2)$.

We then have $rk(T_2 T_1)  < rk(T_1)$

But $rk(T_1) \leq dim(U)$, so $rk(T_2T_1) < dim(U)$ and $dim ker(T_2T_1) > 0$ : $T_2T_1$ is not injective.

Also take $X\in \mathbb R^n$ different from zero. You have two matrices (of rank 1) $X$ and ${}^tX$, The 1-1 matrix ${}^tX \cdot X$ is non null and then injective. $X$ is not injective (if $n> 1$) nor ${}^tX$.